# Can I automate logging in to the box.net widget?

Tags: box-api

The box.net widget that allows uploading/downloading and viewing file works well.

But I need to automate the login process so that others that I allow to my website don't need to know the username and password used for my account.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to use the embed widget which is outlined here: https://support.box.com/entries/20361321-how-to-use-the-file-embed-widget-to-give-access-to-my-box-files-from-my-website

The user will need to log in to their own Box account, but will still be able to upload to the folder.

Comment: I was hoping I could automate the login with an API call.

Comment: Automating login to a single Box account for multiple individuals to use is against our ToS, unfortunately.